# RNN is not overfitting on simple data

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to predict class for each number in input vector. There are 3 classes. Class 1, if input value changed from 0 to 1. Class 2, if it changed from 1 to 0. Class 0 otherwise.

After second epoch and onward accuracy is stuck at 0.8824. Higher number of training epoch does not change anything. I have tried switching `LSTM` to `GRU` or `SimpleRNN`, this changes nothing. I also tried to generate longer input vectors and multiple batches, same without success.

Only thing that helped is  increasing size of LSTM layers to 128, adding three `TimeDistributedDense(128, relu)` layers and `BatchNormalization` after each layer including LSTM. But it looks like overkill for such a simple problem and not giving perfect results anyway.

I've spend more than a day trying to make it work. What could be a problem? 
Thanks!

```
# complete code for training
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM, TimeDistributed
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1337)

X = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
Y = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
Y_cat = to_categorical(Y, 3).reshape((1, len(X), 3))
X_r = X.reshape((1, len(X), 1))

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(32, input_dim=1, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(3, activation='softmax')))

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_r, Y_cat, nb_epoch=10)

model.predict_classes(X_r) # will print array filled with zeros
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could tell that something was wrong because the loss value with your code was NaN after the first epoch. The problem is a common catch that has bitten me more than once in the past, which is that the `fit` method takes a `batch_size` parameter that defaults to 32. Since you only have one example you cannot even fill one batch, a situation that apparently is not detected by Keras but will cause wrong loss calculation. So you just need to change it to:

```
model.fit(X_r, Y_cat, nb_epoch=10, batch_size=1)
```

Still, it might to take some effort to fit that data. It can be hard for a neural net to work with a single feature (maybe it would be easier if the input was one-hot encoded) and the data is tiny. Also, the bigger/deeper the net the more it will take to fit the weights (even if it is supposed to be more powerful). But at least now you will be able to see how the loss decreases. I have been able to reach 100% accuracy with your example removing the second and third LSTM layer and training for around 250 epochs (of course if you had more and longer examples the number would surely be smaller).

Comment: Thanks! Although I have no NaNs at any epoch, removing two LSTM layers and training for 250 epochs did help.

Comment: Also, I found that with Adam(lr=0.05) optimizer it fully trains in about 30 epochs.

Comment: @SSS Right, I see now that I had Keras 1.2.0 instead of the latest 1.2.1. After updating the NaNs are not there anymore, so I guess the problem was fixed in the newer version.